# How to set visibility of ImageButton

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a ImageButton that I would like to remove based on the availability of flash on the users phone. I'm just stuck on setting visibility in Kotlin.

Here is my code:

```
private fun checkForFlashAvailability() {
  try {
    val isFlashAvailable = camera?.cameraInfo?.hasFlashUnit() ? : false

    //SOMETHING HERE TO SET VISIBILITY 

  } catch (e: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
    Logger.warning(TAG, "Cannot get flash available information: ${e.message}")
  }
}
```

I know it has to follow a similar code structure to this:

```
bottomAppBar.menu.findItem(R.id.menu_flash).isVisible = isFlashAvailable
```

Here is the XML:

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/flash_button"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xlarge"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/switch_camera_button_alt"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_off" />
```

Comment: have you simply tried flash_button.isVisible = true ? Android studio should let you import the view with a synthetic import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/ImageView) inherit from [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View), and hence it does have a function `setVisibility(visibility: Int)`, that you can use to set its visibility.

There are 3 types of visibility available.

- [View.VISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#VISIBLE:kotlin.Int) - This view is visible.
- [View.INVISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#INVISIBLE:kotlin.Int) - This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
- [View.GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#gone) - This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Example of setting the visibility:

```kotlin
val isFlashAvailable = camera?.cameraInfo?.hasFlashUnit() ?: false

val view: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.flash_button)
view.setVisibility(
    // Using GONE since we won't need it, CameraInfo.hasFlashUnit() will never change.
    if (isFlashVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I'm getting an error with the findViewById, here is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/3COqYAD  ... also a few things its isFlashAvailable and its a ImageButton not an ImageView. however after chaining these I still get the findViewById error. I should also mention this is a fragment

Comment: @Joe activity implements findViewById, are you calling it somewhere else? In a fragment you can call it on a View, inside onCreateView(). Yea if its imagebutton it also inherit from View and ImageView so you should be able to set its visibility through setVisibility. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton you can always downcast it to ImageButton as well as upcast to view if you want, by changing the type (it will be passed as generic automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself with a combination of answers provided here!

Here is the final solution:

```
    private fun checkForFlashAvailability() {
        try {
            val isFlashAvailable = camera?.cameraInfo?.hasFlashUnit() ?: false
            flash_button.visibility = if (isFlashAvailable) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

        } catch (e: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
            Logger.warning(TAG, "Cannot get flash available information: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
```